# Numpy - Find product Ax=b of custom A nxn matrix and B nx1

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multiplication

Want to find x , from Ax=b .First of all I have declared two matrices , `A` which is `nxn` and `B` `nx1` . Their formulas can be seen below.
For A:
[image]

and for b :
[image]

The matrices can take any `n`. In my code I'm giving it a value of `10`. I declare them by set them to `zero` first . Then f I declare each element of `1,2` and `n-1` and `n` line for both matrices . For `A` I also loop each number to get the desired look , each same number goes one col and row forward , from `n=2` until `n-2`. Then for calculating the `Ax=b` , for finding `x` , I use the multiplication :

```
x = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(A), b)
```

but doesn't get the correct answer . Any help ? I'm posting also my code in its entirety:

```
import numpy as np

n = 10

################## AAAAA matrix #############################################
A = np.zeros([n, n], dtype=float)  # initialize to f zeros

# ------------------first row
A[0][0] = 6
A[0][1] = -4
A[0][2] = 1
# ------------------second row
A[1][0] = -4
A[1][1] = 6
A[1][2] = -4
A[1][3] = 1
# --------------two last rows-----
# n-2 row
A[- 2][- 1] = -4
A[- 2][- 2] = 6
A[- 2][- 3] = -4
A[- 2][- 4] = 1
# n-1 row
A[- 1][- 1] = 6
A[- 1][- 2] = -4
A[- 1][- 3] = 1

# --------------------------- from second to n-2 row --------------------------#
j = 0
for i in range(2, n - 2):
    if j == (n - 4):
        break
    A[i][j] = 1
    j = j + 1

j = 1
for i in range(2, n - 2):
    if j == (n - 3):
        break
    A[i][j] = -4
    j = j + 1

j = 2
for i in range(2, n - 2):
    if j == (n - 2):
        break
    A[i][j] = 6
    j = j + 1

j = 3
for i in range(2, n - 2):
    if j == (n - 1):
        break
    A[i][j] = -4
    j = j + 1

j = 4
for i in range(2, n - 2):
    if j == (n):
        break
    A[i][j] = 1
    j = j + 1
# -----------------------------end coding of 2nd to n-2 r-------------#
print("\nMatrix A is : \n", A)

####### b matrix ######################################
b = np.zeros(n,float).reshape((n,1))
b[0] = 3
b[1] = -1
#b[len(b) - 1] = 3
#b[len(b) - 2] = -1
b[[0,-1]]=3; b[[1,-2]]=-1

print("\nMatrix b is \n", b)

#################### result ########################
x = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(A), b)

print("\n\n The result is : \n", x)
```

Actually I get all `1s` for result , as you can see :

[image]

Comment: It's more idiomatic to use the `x[i, j]` style of indexing.  Also `A[-2, -1]`

Comment: You might like to multiply both sides of equation (leftwise) by inverse of A

Comment: I think I did that , check my loops

Comment: Alright so we need to debug whether `np.linalg.inv(A)`or `np.dot(..., b)` is wrong and that's it.

Comment: You need a more readable implementation of matrix. Try `A = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]], dtype=float)`. Does `np.linalg.inv(A)` work as expected?

Comment: I see . I was looking for a way to find x from Ax=b , and I found np.linalg.inv(A) np.dot(..., b) here on stack, couldn't find much for matrix mult in numpy

Comment: Well, I do not remember how to multiply matrixes too, but I would go on for sure. Just keep searching.

Comment: You can try to check your result like this:  `print(np.dot(A, x))` — if the result were equal to your `b` then your `x` is indeed the correct solution of the problem, even if it may seeem strange to you...

Comment: haha just a misanderstanding , though when I try to run it for a large n , say 10000 the result i get is zeros

Comment: Usually a solver, like `np.linalg.solve` is recommended instead of `np.linalg.inv`.  Infact `inv` is often calculated with `solve(A, eye(n))`.

Comment: tried also x = np.dot(A,b) and got different result , the one i got in a math site when i was double checking the result of mult . I'm stikk a vit confused in which should I use , np.linalg or np.dot

Comment: also checking it with solving math , can be all ones , for example it's clear the first element of the result for example should be 22.

Comment: https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/routines.linalg.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) method makes it:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]], dtype=float)
B = np.array([[3], [4]])
print(np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(A), B))
```

Comment: @KevinWendellCrumb I have just googled `numpy multiple matrices` and tested if it works with `np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(A), A)`

Comment: Thank you for your research . Unfortunately i get the same result . Maybe the fault is elsewhere

Comment: Still getting the same result :-(

Comment: I'm sorry my bad I think it's the right one , thanks for all the edits http://www.bluebit.gr/matrix-calculator/solve.aspx

Comment: Or with operator, `np.linalg.inv(A)@B`.  Also `np.linalg.solve(A,B)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

```
# create matrix A
n=10
row = np.zeros(n+4)
row[:5] = [1,-4,6,-4,1]

A = np.zeros((n,n+4))
for i in range(n):
    A[i] = np.roll(row, i)

A = A[:,2:-2]

# create vector b
b = np.zeros(n)
b[[0,-1]] = 3
b[[1,-2]] = -1

# solution
x = np.linalg.inv(A) @ b  # equivalent to np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(A), b)
```

Output (`x`):

```
array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]
```

which you also obtain. Why do you think that this is not correct?

Comment: I went to a site for matrix computation , in which you put the value of elements one by one and gor different result . You think maybe I got something wrong ?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is what A looks like for small n, like n=3

Comment: I see . I don't really know what's happening to be honest , and I'm pretty inexperienced with this

Comment: it is the right one after all thanks for all your input and help